# Netsuite Saved Search Spacing

Tags: sql, netsuite, saved-searches

I have a search that is main line = false, It's a basic backlog report that has to be set up this way to look at non-invoiced lines.  I am trying to edit my saved search to input a blank line every time there is a document number change.  For example,

SO00412 item sell cost gp
SO00412 item sell cost gp
SO00412 item sell cost gp
Blank LINE
SO00413 item sell cost gp
BLANK LINE
SO00414 item sell cost gp

I have all the fields on there correctly, just want the space to break the report up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Saved searches aren't really built to do this, but you could theoretically manipulate it by inserting the main line into the search results and using formulas to force the main line to read as blank.

I don't believe you can reference the main line in a formula, so it would need to be based on the Line ID. You Might want to try something like:

```
CASE WHEN {line} = 0 THEN '' ELSE {tranid} END
```

> Note: **This would not work for journals or any journal-type transaction types which the main line is always true.**